# why is my SetBookTitle not storing the strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, variables

Strangely when I enter a title for the member to store it doesn't store it what is wrong with it. I dont know what the problem is i have tried a lot of things. I know the median variable works fine but the actual class member function storing doesn't work please help.

```
 class BookType
{
private:
    string Bookinfo;
    string BookTitle;
    string publisher;
    double price;
    int ISBN;
    string authors[4];
    int tracka;
    int copy;
    int Booktracker;

public:
    BookType()
    {

    }
    void setpub(const std::string &pr)
    {
         publisher = pr;
    }
    string getpub()
    {
        return publisher;
    }
    void setcopy(int c)
    {
    int copy = c;
    }
    int getcopy()
    {
        return copy;
    }
    void setprice(double p)
    {
    double price = p;
    }
    double getprice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    void SetBookTitle(const std::string &BT)
    {
        BookTitle = BT;
    }
    string GetBookTitle()
    {
        return BookTitle;
    }
    void SetISBN(int I)
    {
         ISBN = I;
    }
    int GetISBN()
    {
        return ISBN;
    }
    void setnumAuthor(int a)
    {
        tracka = a;
    }
    void setauthor(const std::string &a, int tracka)
    {
        for (int tracka; tracka<4; tracka++)
        {
            authors[tracka] = a;
        }
    }
    void setTBook(int T)
    {
        Booktracker = T;
    }
    string getauthor()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            return authors[i];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{



    optionmenu();


    system("pause");
        return 0;
}

void optionmenu()
{
    BookType Book[10];
    int a = 0;
    string title;
    int isbn;
    int i = 0;
    string nu;
    string author;
    char choice;
    string pub;
    double price;
    int copy;
    int ch;
    string srch;
    bool found = false;

    cout << "Hello welcome to the Bookinfo site please select an option." << endl;
    cout << " do you wish to continue the book info program? 1 for yes any key for no!" ; cin >> ch;
    while (ch == 1)
    {

    MenuOptions();
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {

    case '1': 

    while (i >= 10)
    {
        cout << "you have reached he book limit, choose another menu option!"; cin >> choice;
    }
    cout << i << endl;

    cout << i << endl;
        cout << "=====================" << endl;
        getline(cin, nu);
        cout << "Please enter book title" << endl;
        getline(cin,title);
    Book[i].SetBookTitle(title);
if (choice = '1')
    {
        i++;
    }

        cout << "please enter the author(s) name(s), if less then 4 authors leave (NA) in the leftover blanks." << endl;
        for (int ai = 0;  ai < 4; ai++)
        {
        getline(cin, author);   
        Book[i].setnumAuthor(ai);
        }
        cout << "=======================================================" << endl;
        cout << "please enter the books ISBN Number." << endl;
        cin >> isbn;
        Book[i].SetISBN(isbn);


        cout << "what is the publisher of the book?" << endl;
        getline(cin, nu);
        getline(cin, pub);

        Book[i].setpub(pub);
```

Comment: `string BookTitle = BT;` This is creating a variable that has the same name as your membervariable and assigning BT to it. Remove the type: `BookTitle = BT;`

Comment: Please read a good book (covering C/C++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void SetBookTitle(string BT)
{
    string BookTitle = BT; //Does not assign to class member
}
```

This creates a new function local variable `BookTitle` that *hides* the class member. When the function goes out of scope, the value is not kept.

It should look more like this:

```
void SetBookTitle(const std::string &BT)
{
    BookTitle = BT;
}
```

Comment: Getting into the habit of using distinct naming conventions for members and stack variables is also very useful. Prepending members with "m_" -> `m_someVarName` is quite common for instance.

Comment: wow ok so what is actually happening now that didn't happen before

Comment: hello the same thing is happening to my publisher,ISBN,Price, and authors. Mainly the authors and publishers

Comment: @LegacyWink the problem is the same... take out the *type* in front (that makes it a new variable local to the scope of the function). You might also want to use a different case or naming convention for local variables vs. class members. Your `setauthor` is also wrong by creating a new *uninitialized* `tracka` local to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the variable name.

```
void SetBookTitle(string BT)
{
    string BookTitle = BT;
}
```

Should be:

```
void SetBookTitle(string BT)
{
    BookTitle = BT;
}
```

I tend to use `this->` to be sure I'm using the class member.

Comment: ok cool thanks i did'nt realize the string before booktitle was messing it up